# No answer section using dig

Tags: dns, ipv6

I've got an assignment from school to setup a DNS server with 2 name servers in ubuntu server using IPv6, but I'm not very good at it. When I use the dig command, **It doesn't show an answer section**.

Does anyone got an idea why this is the case and how I can solve it?

```
dig @127.0.0.1 mickey.acme.exa
```

http://snag.gy/Gv1hx.jpg

Here you can see some config files:

In /etc/bind/named.conf.options I left the forwarders { 0.0.0.0; }; in comment. I don't know if I really need this or not.

**/etc/bind/db.acme.exa**

http://snag.gy/OU7RL.jpg

**/etc/bind/named.conf.local**

```
zone "acme.exa" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/db.acme.exa";
};
```

Answer (score 3):

In the future, please copy & paste the textual information that is relevant to the question instead of taking a screenshot and hosting it on some external site. In addition to making your question not self-contained, you make your question less searchable and less accessible to people with visual disabilities.

That being said, everything looks normal here:

- From your second screenshot, it seems you have given `mickey.acme.exa` just a `AAAA` record and nothing else.
- From your first screenshot, you have asked for the `A` record corresponding to `mickey.acme.exa`. It replied to you with `NOERROR` (because the name exists) but zero answers (because there is no `A` record as requested).

Comment: oh excuse me for that. And what else do I have to give mickey.acme.exa then? I don't know much about this. You said I asked for the A record, how can I ask for the AAAA record instead? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Oow I just put AAAA at the end of my digcommand to get the answer section

Answer (score 0):

Another reason ANSWER SECTION can be missing is that there was no domain found to look for your A record in. For example, if you passed `dig` an URL (`dig http://example.com`) instead of a domain name (`dig example.com`), it will tell you NXDOMAIN (non-existent domain).

```
dig http://example.com

;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 38729
```